# Excel Aggregate - adress of the result?

Tags: excel, aggregate

Good day to you, sir/madame!

I have a table like this:

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C     |
--+-----+-----+--------+
1 |  2  |  2  |  Test1 |
2 |  1  |  2  |  Test2 |
3 |  2  |  9  |  Test3 |
4 |  3  |  4  |  Test4 |
```

I want get the name in column 'C' where the biggest differences are between column 'B' and 'A' without having to use another cell for the differences. In this case, my desired result would be: 'Test3' (biggest difference: 7).

I got this formula for catching the biggest difference:

```
=AGGREGATE(14;6;B:B-A:A;1)
```

Which gets me a plain number '7'.

For the next step, INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP seems promising.

```
=INDEX(C:C;MATCH(??;A:A;0))
```

or

```
=VLOOKUP(??;A:I;3)
```

But i can't understand how i can combine the 'Aggregate' function into INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP. Or should i do something completly different? Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the result of the maximum difference (7 in your example) in `E2` then you can use this "array formula" in `F2` for the value from column C

`=INDEX(C1:C4,MATCH(E2,ABS(B1:B4-A1:A4),0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You can avoid "array entry" by using an additional `INDEX` function, i.e.

`=INDEX(C1:C4,MATCH(E2,INDEX(ABS(B1:B4-A1:A4),0),0))`

Comment: yay thanks! i combinend 'Aggregate' and your formula like this:

`=INDEX(C1:C4;MATCH(AGGREGATE(14;6;B:B-A:A;1);INDEX(ABS(B1:B4-A1:A4);0);0))`

Answer (score 0):

In **D1** enter:

```
=ABS(A1-B1)
```

and copy down

then use:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(MAX(D:D),D:D,0))
```

For example:

[image: xx]

Comment: thanks for that, but i really don't want to use another column for that (all in all it's a complex spreadsheet). is there no way to make this directly in one cell?